# Android unit test - assertEqual not working with Locale values

Tags: android, unit-testing, locale

I am trying to write a Localization class to convert numbers and currencies from a given paragraph. Here is the test case i am trying to run.

```
@Test
public void localContentTest() throws Exception {
    String content = "Go Square Wakad, 411057 Pune";
    String expectedContent = "Go Square Wakad, 411057 Pune";
    String actualString = Localization.localeContent(content, Locale.GERMAN);
    assertEquals(expectedContent, actualString);
}
```

The `Localization.localeContent` is simple function that returns string.

```
 public static String localeContent(final String content, final Locale locale) {
        final StringBuilder stringBuilderResult = new StringBuilder();
        ... 
        //Something to extract number and get it localize.

        return stringBuilderResult.toString();
    }
```

In test output i am getting this. What's not clear to me is why the test is failing even when the **expected and actual is same**.

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :Go Square Wakad, 411057 Pune
Actual   :Go Square Wakad, 411057 Pune 
 <Click to see difference>


    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:100)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:107)
    at localizationdemo.com.localizationdemo.LocalizationTest.localContentTestForNoDecimalValues(LocalizationTest.java:333)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have a whitespace at the end of your actual string:

```
Expected :"Go Square Wakad, 411057 Pune"
Actual   :"Go Square Wakad, 411057 Pune "
```

If not, pls share with us the code you used to generate the actual string.

Comment: LOL, I am gonna kill myself.. that was it ... You are awesome man. Thanx. I have to ask, how did you get double quotes in your "Expected" and "Actual".

Comment: I just posted the quotes to make my point clear, thats not actually console output :P
But what you can do is check and compare the string length; if the strings look the same but do not have the same length they probably have some whitespace at the end.